# How to print unichar in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

just a quick question about Objective-C. I'm using xcode9, when I was trying to print unichar by NSLog, it doesn't show anything in console. anyone know what happened?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSString *str = @"DI Love You!";
    unichar ch = [str characterAtIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"ch = %C", ch);


    return 0;
}
```

Output: ch =

tried %c and %C, both not working.

Comment: OC? I assume you mean Objective-C, in which case, please say that and add the relevant tag.

Comment: sorry mate, OC = Objective-C

Comment: Your code is fine. The character at index 2 is a space.

Comment: oh...that's embarrassing...I didn't realize that I put a "D" at beginning...lol, thanks buddy